# Ruby 2.5 activesupport ubuntu conflicts with i18n

Tags: ruby, rails-i18n, activesupport

I wanna run a simple script with made on Ruby, when i try to run it i get the next error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from thread.py:6:in `<main>'
    5: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    4: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    3: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `try_activate'
    2: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:224:in `rescue in try_activate'
    1: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1437:in `activate'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2324:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate activesupport-5.1.5, because i18n-1.0.0 conflicts with i18n (~> 0.7) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

My Ruby version is:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Too little information. Are you using Bundler? What's the Gemfile? If not using Bundler, what are your `require` statements?

Comment: Hi @Casper i just run "gem install --" with the gems i need, my statements are:

`require 'firebase'
require 'conekta'
require 'json'
require 'savon'
require "crack"
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'  #from_xml 
require 'nokogiri'
require 'xmlsimple'
require 'mysql2'

class Cron  
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the 1.0.0 version if `i18n` was just released, but `activesupport` is not compatible with this version (`~> 0.7`).

One solution is to remove 1.0.0 system-wide, and reinstall 0.9.5 instead, which is the latest version before 1.0.0:

```
gem uninstall i18n --all --force
gem install i18n --version 0.9.5
```

Comment: I get it! You are right it seems that the problem is solved.
Thanks a lot.